# TypeError: rangoDestino.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, types

I have a code in which I want to enter a value in a cell and have it be updated in another cell in another sheet but there is an error that I do not understand, ".map is not a function".

```js
function actualizarValor() {


  //Origen
  var libroOrigen=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen=libroOrigen.getActiveSheet();
  var celdaActiva=libroOrigen.getActiveCell();
  var filaActiva=celdaActiva.getRow();

  var precio=hojaOrigen.getRange(filaActiva, 4)


  //Destino
  var libroDestino=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KGVgxcZDhZEk7EEj94sYZasR1QbrB8vW058B9h4aSg8/edit#gid=0")
  var hojaDestino=libroDestino.getSheetByName("datos");
  var rangoDestino=hojaDestino.getDataRange();
  Logger.log(rangoDestino)
  var listaIDsDestino=rangoDestino.map(fila=>fila[0])  
  Logger.log(listaIDsDestino);
  Logger.log(precio);

}
```

Comment: `rangoDestino` is a Range object.  I think what you want is `rangoDestino.getValues()`?  You could have just as easily done `var rangoDestino=hojaDestino.getRange(1,1,hojaDestino.getLastRow(),1).getValues()` and you would be getting the values from column A.

Comment: A range is not an Array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bienvenido a [so] Antonio. When posting a question about code that is not working, please instead of adding the original code create a [mcve]. If you are considering to ask a question here, take that opportunity to use variable names and comments in English . Also use spaces to make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var listaIDsDestino=rangoDestino.map(fila=>fila[0])
```

by

```
var listaIDsDestino = rangoDestino.getValues().map(fila => fila[0])
```

---

It's very likely that you forgot to use `SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues()` or another similar method that returns a 2D Array, just in case...

`SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange()` returns a Class Range object. This class hasn't a method called `map`.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)